# How can I force the class name order with ng-class

Tags: angularjs, semantic-ui, ng-class

I am using semantic ui and angular (1.4) ui to build an application. I am experiencing a situation where adding the class names dynamically via angular results in incorrect rendering because ng-class seems to rearrange the class names at will. This is undesirable, because semantic expects certain class name combinations to follow natural/semantic order. Example:

```
<div class="ui two column grid">
   <div ng-class="wideVersion? 'sixteen wide column': 'fourteen wide column'"></div>
</div>
```

This results (when the scope variable wideVersion changes) in a dom of:

```
<div class="ui two column grid">
   <div class="wide column fourteen"></div>
</div>
```

This does not work, because semantic requires the classnames to follow natural order in this use case. I have tried multiple ng-class variations but the outcome is the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `ng-attr-class` or just class with interpolation inside.
But there are cases where angular is adding classes to elements automatically, for instance `ng-show` and form inputs, so you might need to find a more complete solution.

```js
angular.module('test', [])

.controller('Test', function($scope){
  
});
```

```css
.test.one.two {
  color:red;
}

.test.three.four {
  color:blue;
}

.test.five.six {
  color:green;
}

.test.seven.eight {
  color:pink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='test' ng-controller='Test'>
  <div ng-attr-class="{{checked ? 'test one two' : 'test three four'}}">test1</div>
  <div class="{{checked ? 'test five six' : 'test seven eight'}}">test2</div>
  <input type='checkbox' ng-model='checked'> click
</div>
```

Comment: This does not work either. The class names still get arranged out of the order specified.

Comment: Hmm can you reproduce using snippet or fiddle?